# React NavLink: isActive function throws 'string is not assignable to type string | undefined'

Tags: reactjs, react-router, navigation

I defined NavLinks for styling an active link.

For instance I tried several approaches of this kind:

```
<NavLink to="contact" className={({ isActive }) => (isActive ? 'nav-links-active' : 'nav-links')}>
      Contact
</NavLink>
```

This doesn't work and the IDE returns:

Type function({isActive: any}): string | string is not assignable to type string | undefined   Type function({isActive: any}): string | string is not assignable to type string

Do I have to define isActive somewhere? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you can try this: className={isActive ? 'nav-links-active' : 'nav-links}

Comment: What version of `react-router` is installed? You can check by running from the project's directory `npm list react-router` and report back the installed version. Can you also update the post to include a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that includes all relevant component/linking code you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Use `activeClassName` instead. You can simply do this:

```js
<NavLink to="contact" activeClassName='nav-links-active' className='nav-links'>
      Contact
</NavLink>
```

But it works in react-router-dom v5. It does not exist in v6 anymore. For further details [see documentation](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/NavLink/activeclassname-string)

Answer (score 0):

> By default, an active class is added to a  component when it
> is active. This provides the same simple styling mechanism for most
> users who are upgrading from v5. One difference as of v6.0.0-beta.3 is
> that activeClassName and activeStyle have been removed from
> NavLinkProps. Instead, you can pass a function to either style or
> className that will allow you to customize the inline styling or the
> class string based on the component's active state. You can also pass
> a function as children to customize the content of the 
> component based on their active state, specially useful to change
> styles on internal elements.

Answer (score -1):

`className` does not accept callback functions. If `isActive` a variable or a state you can simply do this:

```js
<NavLink to="contact" className={isActive ? 'nav-links-active' : 'nav-links'}>
      Contact
</NavLink>
```

Comment: in my implementation, I didn't define isActive. I want to check if the nav link contact is clicked and set a new style. Doesn't isActive check if the corresponding link is clicked? Or do I have to implement isActive on links?

Comment: You can define a state and set its value to `true` in a click event.

Comment: The RRD [v5](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/NavLink/classname-string-func) and [v6](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/components/nav-link) `NavLink` components ***certainly*** take a string ***or*** a callback function on the `className` prop. Please check documentation before making/asserting claims.

Comment: I read the API which you linked, using the code from the API still gives me:
Type function({isActive: any}): any | undefined is not assignable to type CSSProperties | undefined   Type function({isActive: any}): any | undefined is not assignable to type CSSProperties.

Any idea?